# Logging into the Android App using Google on Android 6.0

Tags: bug, android-app, login, google-openid

Last night I decided to upgrade my phone to Android 6.0 and noticed I am unable to log into the app anymore. I have always used Google as my login for the site and I was logged into the app just yesterday, before upgrading to 6.0.

I double checked that I don't have a password associated with my account by using the "forgot" link and did get back a confirmation email saying that I don't have a password associated with my account and that I can login using my Google account.

Yet this is what my login screen looks like on my 6.0 phone.

[image: Android 6.0 Login Screen]

And on my 5.1.1 tablet it looks like this.

[image: With Android 5.1.1]]

Looks like a new permission model issue causing the Google login not to show up on Android 6.0, and because I do not have a password associated with my Stack Exchange account, I am unable to login.

Comment: Have you checked if the "Contact" permission is allowed for Stack Exchange app? You can check by going to "App info" and then go to "Permissions".

Comment: No Permissions granted; however I was able to manually enable it and that *worked*. Since I did a fresh install of 6.0 and had all of my apps restored during the phone setup process figured I'd try deleting all data and trying again but that did not work. I didn't think of enabling the permission manually so thanks for that! Anyone know if the `Storage` Permission is needed?

Comment: @AndrewT. sounds like it's worth an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: as of v1.0.77, the app will show <kbd>Log in using Google</kbd> regardless if *Contact* permission is enabled or not. If it's disabled, the app will prompt the user to allow accessing the contact.

[image: login selection] [image: contact permission dialog]

> Fixes an issue that didn't allow Google sign-in on Android 6.0 devices

---

*tl;dr* go to Stack Exchange's "App info", open "Permissions", and enable "Contact".

Android app needs *Contact* permission for managing accounts on their device, including detecting and using existing Google account as login credential.

Since Android 6.0, [the permission model is changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) so that users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime.

It seems there's a bug in Android when a user does a fresh install of Android 6.0 (compared to just updating), where permission settings might be lost after restoring the apps. (*not yet proven, but [similar issue already occured](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125063/applications-lost-permissions-after-flashing-marshmallow)*)

You need to manually enable the contact permission by:

1. Access the "App info" (either by dragging the app from launcher to "App info" on the top, or from Settings - Apps - Stack Exchange)
2. Open "Permissions" setting
3. Enable "Contact" permission

Now you should be able to use Google for login credential again.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I did try clearing cache/data and that also did not work, so it seems like an issue with the app. I looked through some a number of other apps and it looks like 1 or 2 had the the same issue.

Comment: Updating the app with the latest version of the Google Sign-In SDK will completely eliminate this issue: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/11/improvements-to-sign-in-with-google.html ... API update is pretty straightforward: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html